# application has stopped working vb.net

Tags: vb.net

today I imported my project in visual studio 2013 as I need the framework 4.5 to work with some components. When I start the application in debug it works beautifully, but when I take exe from the folder bin / debug and start clicking on it, I get this text:

[image: http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/79fc/j0o32gwetsd3ct6fg.jpg]

What is it that gives rise to this error? I have not the faintest idea, and the network can not find effective solutions.

Comment: Image isn't available....

Comment: check again, i see the image correctly

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my mistake.  I was manually typing the address into my phone to see the image.  Is that in Italian??

Comment: I see it, I just can't read it!

Comment: Where are you taking the debug exe and putting it?  I'm wondering if you're putting it on a different machine without access to debug resources.

Comment: I have attached the image because it tells me that other details are available in the paths that you see in the image. 
The program starts when do I debug in visual studio 2013, at the contrary, however, when I execute this exe in bin / debug I can not start giving me this error.